# Optimizing VB.NET LINQ Query with multiple string contains?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to optimize the following LINQ query, performance is subjective so providing some details below on this aspect.

```
 Dim _calls = (From p In db.PhoneLogs.AsNoTracking Where 
    p.from_caller_id.Contains(Phone1) Or p.to_caller_id.Contains(Phone1) _
    p.from_caller_id.Contains(Phone2) Or p.to_caller_id.Contains(Phone2) _
    ).ToList()
```

**Given the following:**

- `from/to_caller_id` column is string, the values could be: `915555555555` or `JOHNNY <5555555555>` or `915555555555`
- `Phone1` is parsed to a 10 digit number removing any leading `+1` ex: `5555555555`
- `Phone2` is parsed to a 12 digit number removing any leading `+` ex: `915555555555`
- I can't modify the database schema

**Performance**

- I'm not able to get the query to execute in < 5 seconds.
- The to_/from_ columns are full text indexed, does not make a significant performance improvement.
- I am forced to drop it to a list, as i must iterate through the objects, but the performance impact is low as a typically return is < 5 records, with the largest return being around 20 records or so.
- Each entity object return only has 10 props, all are needed.

Comment: If you has full text indexes, use `EF.Functions.Contains`

Comment: There are hard limits to what you can do. If these are full text indexes then about the best you will get is ensuring you are executing a full text search which will depend on the EF version you are running. Beyond that, throwing more hardware at it. Can they narrow down by something indexable like date range? Personally I would suggest they consider adjusting the schema to include a sanitized phone number that can be indexed and searched with an == match.  Better than trying to get blood from a stone.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option here is getting to raw SQL, because then you can do this (I don't recall a way to use table-value constructors with linq):

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM AsNoTracking p
INNER JOIN (VALUES
    (@Phone1),
    (@Phone2)
) filter(Phone) ON CONTAINS(p.from_caller_id, filter.Phone)
    OR CONTAINS(p.to_caller_id, filter.Phone)
```

Or you can do this, which should at least be possible to convert to Linq (see `EF.Functions.Contains()`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM AsNoTracking 
WHERE CONTAINS(from_caller_id, @Phone1)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM AsNoTracking 
WHERE CONTAINS(to_caller_id, @Phone1)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM AsNoTracking 
WHERE CONTAINS(from_caller_id, @Phone2)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM AsNoTracking 
WHERE CONTAINS(to_caller_id, @Phone2)
```

But the Linq code will be ugly and I've never seen the point of writing SQL to just convert to linq to convert back to SQL.